# Adding the row ID to the filename of the uploaded file

Tags: php, html

I want to add the ID number of the row to the uploaded file file name.
e.g. if the file name is stack.pdf before uploading, after uploading it should change to stack-ID#.pdf.

***This is the PHP Codes that is use to upload***

```
$sp=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ara");
         if($sp->connect_errno){
                echo "Error <br/>".$sp->error;
}

$path="pdf/";

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{

$path=$path.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'],$path))
{
echo " ".basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name'])." has been uploaded<br/>";
echo '<img src="gallery/'.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'].'" width="48" height="48"/>';
$img=$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $query="insert into library (path,CreatedTime) values('$img',now())";
    if($sp->query($query)){
     echo "<br/>Inserted to DB also";    
    }else{
        echo "Error <br/>".$sp->error;        
    }
}
else
{
echo "There is an error,please retry or ckeck path";
}
}
```

***And this is the form***

```
<form action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="384" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="108">Select File</td>
<td width="260"><label>
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
</label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$uploadFileName = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];


//get extention of upload file
$attachment_ext =  explode('.', $uploadFileName);
$ext_pt = $attachment_ext[1];

//Give a new name for the file
$newName = '123'.$uploadFileName.".".$ext_pt;

$path = "YOURPATHHERE/";

$save_attchment = $path.$newName ; //setting the path

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $save_attchment);
```